# C# Simplifying string array initialization

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

C# Simplifying string array initialization. Is there a way to optimize the below code in C#

```
string[] createdBy = new string[totalRowCount];
for (long i = 0; i < totalRowCount; i++)
{
    createdBy[i] = userName;
}
```

Also

```
int?[] defaultInd = new int?[totalRowCount];
        for (long i = 0; i < totalRowCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                defaultInd[i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                defaultInd[i] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, just want to offer some alternative advice since the answers below give you what you want. IMHO you should go for readability over clever syntactic sugar. I doubt there'll be a noticeable performance increase by using the shortened methods and you're just making things harder to debug if anything goes wrong here since I assume you're not overly familiar with the syntax. Just my two cents ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] myIntArray = Enumerable.Repeat(userName, totalRowCount).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct repeated sequences:

```
string[] createdBy = Enumerable.Range(0, totalRowCount)
    .Select(i => userName)
    .ToArray();
int?[] defaultInd = Enumerable.Range(0, totalRowCount)
    .Select(i => i==0 ? (int?)1 : 0)
    .ToArray();
```

Note how the first lambda expression does not use the value of index `i`, because all elements are set to the same string.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many ways to simplify that for loop in both examples, unless you use Enumeration.Range, as shown in the other answers. However, in your second example, you could use the ternary operator:

```
defaultInd[i] = i == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```